# Get Brew to use Python 2.7.3

Tags: python

I am trying to install opencv which requires Python 2.7.3 to install. However, in terminal my python continues to point to 2.7.2 although I have installed the 2.7.3 installer from the python website.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Mac OS X uses the default version of Python... I wouldn't remove it.

Comment: Don't remove 2.7.2, never touch the system version if you're on Mac.

Comment: Listen to RyPeck and Leigh! DO NOT remove the system version(s) of Python! I had this bright idea once on Debian Linux and it was easier to just reinstall the system from scratch afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Homebrew to install the newer version of Python for you:

```
brew install python
```

If you've got [Homebrew installed](http://brew.sh/#install) (and reading between the lines, assuming you're using Mac OS X).

Homebrew will install to a different place than the system version (2.7.2) so if we want to update or remove this Homebrew version later on, you can revert back to just using the system version instead since you didn't modify it.